# Horizontal scrolling in Inkscape in Mac OS

Tags: mouse, macos

When I run [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) on Mac OS or in Parallels, the horizontal scrolling works fine when I use the touchpad but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+MouseWheelScroll doesn't do anything. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+MouseWheelScroll works fine (controls zoom). It makes Inkscape very hard to use IMO, as I cannot easily navigate through the drawing without zooming-unzooming all the time.

Such horizontal scrolling works just fine e.g. in the browser (both in Mac and in Parallels).

Is there a way to achieve it also in Inkscape on Mac?

Comment: What type of mouse are you using? I have no problem scrolling horizontally  in Inkscape with an Apple Magic Mouse moving my finger back and forth across the width of the mouse, or if pressing the shift key and moving my finger up and down across the length of the mouse.

Comment: @user3439894, interesting. I have a 10 Euro HP mouse at the moment, with 2 buttons and a wheel. As mentioned, horizontal scroll works (with this mouse) in many places, but not in Inkscape canvas. I would assume that the AMM sort of imitates the touchpad? 'Cause h-scrolling works fine with a 2-finger gesture.

Comment: I'm using a single finger gesture with the AMM, haven't tested with the Trackpad as the MBP is docked in clamshell mode at the moment and not able to test. I highly recommend the Apple Magic Mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Well, having done some more googling, have found this: [no horizontal scroll on OS X](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/167191). Unfortunately, looks like it's a bug in Inkscape (horizontal scrolling works on the colour palette under the canvas) :(

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions to the horizontal scrolling issue in Inkscape. I'm using an old Mac Air with Yosemite and an ancient Logitech track ball with scroll wheel.

1. When I place the cursor anywhere in the horizontal scroll bar "window" along the bottom, moving the scroll wheel alone scrolls the image horizontally (discovered completely accidentally).
2. While holding the scroll wheel down (When I depress mine, there is an audible click. I don't know if all scroll wheels do this), moving the track ball will drag the entire canvas anywhere the track ball goes.

I hope this helps.